# How can I use Simple Form in Rails to only show a specific set of nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, simple-form

I have an has many association on my `School` model called `PlayerScrape`.  I want to use the following code to only show a filtered collection of the association in my form.  How can I do it given the collection `@scraped_records` being my filtered association records?

***The following currently shows the 64 records that are associated with that `School`.***

```
<%= form.simple_fields_for :player_scrapes do |field| %>
```

The collection, `@scraped_records` contains only 13 records of the association that I would like to show in my form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this i guess `form.association :player_scrapes, collection: @scraped_records"`. If this is what you need there is more option for `association` method on their github documentation. Hope it helps.

Comment: can i replace `simple_fields_for` with `association` for building my nested form?

Comment: i think you still need ``simple_fields_for`` to build a nested form, ``association`` is just showing a list of inputs that you have selected as checkbox or radio_buttons.